# ember-collection example not working

Tags: ember.js

I installed the alpha 4* and tried it with the example from README.

However, I only see a container with "height: 500000px" (yes, 500k px) with some of the rendered items (5 of 10k). Scrolling only works with the scrollbar instead of dragging. However, no new items do appear when doing so.

Console throws this error:

fixed-grid.js:74
Uncaught TypeError: height depends on the first argument of visibleWidth(number)

template.hbs:

```
<div class="row" style="height: 500px; background: #CCC;">
  <div class="col-md-12" style="height: 100%; position: relative;">
    {{#ember-collection height=500 width=800 items=model cell-layout=(fixed-grid-layout 800 50) as |item index|}}
      {{item.name}}
    {{/ember-collection}}
  </div>
</div>
```

route.js:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    var items = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
      items.push({name: "Item " + i});
    }
    return items;
  }
});
```

Version: 1.13.8
Chromium: 45.0.2454.101 Ubuntu 14.04 (64-bit)

Is this a bug due to alpha or did I do something wrong?

Regards, haggis

* git://github.com/emberjs/ember-collection.git#d7c453d9400dc9f8c55a6b4b31104abafb47aa61

Answer (score 1):

I see you're using the example from the github page, but the example from the [npmjs.org page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-collection) shows that `height` and `width` of the *container* are explicitly passed in, so you need to add those attributes as well:

```
{{#ember-collection
  items=model
  height=500
  width=800
  cell-layout=(fixed-grid-layout 800 50) as |item index|
}}
  {{name}}
{{/ember-collection}}
```

The pages both also mention that these are [required parameters](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-collection#required-parameters).